# How to check what device are You running in bash

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bash, ipod-touch

I would like to check on what device (iPod/iPhone/iPad) script is running. How can I do that ?
I've looked through the web but I can't find anything usefull..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash try these commands:

```
sysctl hw.model
sysctl hw.machine
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash??

This is how I achieve this (in an iOS app written in Objective-C, the only way on a non-Jailbroken phone):

```
    NSLog(@"%@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]);
```

Check [the UIDevice reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) for what you can access.

Edit: on my Mac, I can run `ioreg -l |grep -i "Device Model Name"` and see my device model. *perhaps* there is a similar thing available in iOS.